# Angular - Cannot access or view selected data from grid in form input box

Tags: angular, primeng, angular7, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I am facing a problem in displaying data of a single row in the input boxes of a form.

Grid View : (Data is stored in selectedTrade array)

```html
<p-table [value]="trades" [paginator]="true" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedTrade">
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-trades>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="trades">
      <td><button pButton #Buy name="Buy" type="button" (click)="showDialog()"></button>
      </td>
      <td><button pButton #Sell name="Sell" type="button" (click)="showDialog()"></button>
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{trades[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Dialog box involves a form with inputboxes. I need the value of **selectedTrade** array in the inputboxes when dialog opens.

**selectedTrade Json structure** { instrumentid : '1', instrument: 'Tesla', buyPrice: '2000', 'buyQty': '9', 'sellPrice':'5000','sellQty':'25'}

I need to bind it with inputs : Instrument , Transaction_Quantity, Transaction_Price depending on the buy or sell dialog box. I am facing problems in binding or displaying values. Please help.

```html
<p-dialog header="Orders" [(visible)]="ordersDialog" [modal]="true">
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(editForm.value)" #editForm="ngForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="instrument_id" id="instrument_id" ngModel #instrument_id="ngModel" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="at_price" id="field_at_price" ngModel #at_price="ngModel" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="transaction_quantity" id="transaction_type" ngModel #transaction_quantity="ngModel" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <span>Save</span></button>
</form>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get the data than need get data from your model(i.e your col )

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="instrument_id" id="instrument_id" [(ngModel)]="col.instrument_id" />
```

Comment: Using <p> {{ selectedTrade | json }}</p> displays me the json structure in the dialog.  Unable to use **selectedTrade.instrument_id** in the input as a display value. **col.instrument_id** would not work. It is in a different context.

Comment: you pass selectedTrade(i.e your json model) as selectedTrade.instrument_id

Comment: it is having in json? check json before is there is present or not??

Comment: {{ selectedTrade | json }} prints the json in my dialog box. It is present.

Comment: than add [(ngModel)]="selectedTrade.instrument_id" this get your id.(i consider your model name selectedTrade. if this different than add that name at selectedTrade.